# ellipsis is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display ellipsis for a breadcrumb. Lets take the li element `home/content/breadcrumb` it should show as `home/.../breadcrumb`. And the ellipsis(...) show be clickable and if user clicks that it should expand.

Not sure how to do that and one of my friend suggested that "write an onClick function using jQuery and inside the function just write code for `addClass` and `removeClass` and style those classes in css to show ellipsis."

```css
.hide {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/" class="hide">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/content" class="hide">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/content/breadcrumbs" class="show">Breadcrumbs</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I have no idea what it mean by. Can some one help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"ellipsis is not working"* - I'm not sure if code that hasn't been written yet can be said to be "not working". Anyway, it doesn't really make sense to display `/home/.../breadcrumb` as the final item in the list as well as separately displaying `/home` and `/home/content` in other list items. if you display `home/.../breadcrumb` then are the `home` part and the `breadcrumb` parts also directly clickable to go to those pages, but clicking the `...` part should expand out the full path?

Answer (score 1):

This should accomplish what you're after.

```js
$('.hide').click(function() {
  $('.hide').toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden a { display: none; }
ol { list-style: none; }
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li:after {
content: '/';
}
.hidden:after {
content: '... /';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="hide hidden">
      <a href="/home/content">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/content/breadcrumbs" class="show">Breadcrumbs</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

#### Edit

Changed the jQuery selector from `.breadcrumbs` to `.hide`. Allows only the `... /` to be clicked and not the entire breadcrumb.

Comment: I have created plunker for this. "..." should be clickable not "home or breadcrumbs". plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/IrtnPLDJ6qqP723TVbEY?p=preview

Comment: @sanju the issue with doing this is once the ellipse is removed there's no easy way to show it again based on the criteria you're asking for. In my example if you want 'Components' to be clickable as a link there's no way to toggle the ellipses back without an additional element or action.

Answer (score 1):

This is pure CSS...

```css
.breadcrumbs ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.breadcrumbs li {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
    padding-right: 7px;
    color: #999;
}

.breadcrumbs li:first-child,
.breadcrumbs li:last-child  {
    display: inline-block;
}

.breadcrumbs li:first-child {
    margin-right: 7px;
}

.breadcrumbs li:first-child::after {
    content: "/... /";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    margin-top: 0;
    right: -10px;
}

.breadcrumbs li a {
    line-height: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    padding: 10px 6px;
    height: 14px;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumbs li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/" class="hide">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/content" class="hide">Components</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/content/breadcrumbs" class="show">Breadcrumbs</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: with this code home and breadcrumbs are clickable but what I need is "..." should be clickable. when user clicks "..." it should expand "content". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do still but still you can try this.
Add a class for all li between home and breadcrumb. Let it be hidden-breadcrumbs.

```
.hidden-breadcrumbs{
display:none;
}
<li class="expander">...</li>
$('.expander'.click(function(){
$(this).hide();
$('.hidden-breadcrumbs').show();
});
```